# Azure Data Explorer: Failed to download blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

Ok so I'm following this Data Explorer tutorial (but adapting it to my own dataset):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-sample-data

I'm running this code:

```
.ingest into table SalesData h'https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/sales/SalesDataSata.csv' with (ignoreFirstRecord=true)
```

But get the error:

```
Failed to download blob: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

I have copied and pasted the BLOB URL from the Portal exactly as is, and all resources belong to the same resource group.

Comment: Ok I see you've edited your question. Note that, for your own blob, if it's a *private* blob, you won't be able to download it without first creating a Shared Access Signature (or policy). Or you can mark the blob as public (but then it's possible that others can find your content).

Comment: OK thanks that helped

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to David Makogon for pointing me towards the right answer.
To make the BLOB accessible you need to generate a SAS URL for the blob file.
Do this by selecting the BLOB file in the Azure Portal then click on the ...
Select Generate SAS then ok.

Comment: The other thing you can do is make the blob publicly accessible. Obviously you should only do this with data that is public or you don't care about.